# draw a simple line graph using C# console application project

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I wanted to know whether a X,Y graph can be plotted from C#'s console application? If so, can anyone please help me out. I am very very new to C# and I am trying to work on a tool which can useful for my group. I want to build a line graph with the following options:
1. from an excel file containing X and Y values with headers
2. random numbers with random headers

and save the chart as either a Bitmap/jpeg file.

I'd really be thankful to whosoever tries and guides me in the right direction and helps me out.

Comment: Since you mentioned excel, [whats wrong with using excel itself?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/creating-xy-scatter-and-line-charts-HA001054840.aspx)

Comment: @L.B.. As I mentioned I am pretty new to C#, if you have any sort of help to give please leave a comment, I'd really appreciate it. If you don't I am not interested in knowing your opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6708/Creating-Line-Chart-For-WebForms-Using-C

For getting the x and y from an excel file, just set it up so you have a streamreader and openfiledialog and you filter out the ',' or whatever it is and then the x and y will both be in an array like [0],[1] and then just use [0] for the x and [1] for the y.

Comment: tried implementing it. I don't why it doesn't work! I even downloaded the source code to try and understand it. it doesn't load the solution.

Comment: @Gouri: Make a WinForms application, not a Console application. Copying the source code of a WinForms application to a Console application won't work!

Comment: Hi Olivier, When I downloaded the source code, doesnt it automatically open it as a winforms application? and just so you know, I did check whether it was a console or a winforms application. It still doesn't load the solution.